# Predis - Removing server from the connection pool

Tags: redis, distributed, failover, predis

Say, I am having N servers in the predis connection pool. I found that when one of the server does down, predis does not work(i.e. new predis/client(s1,s2,...) does not return successfully if any of the server Si is down). First, the entry of that failed server needs to be removed manually, and only after this predis resumes its work.
Since, predis claims to be using consistent hashing, shouldn't this be the case that predis automatically detects which of the server is not responding ( & has failed), and distribute the keys stored on the failed server to the other working servers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Predis does use consistent hashing, but it is left to you to ensure that all servers in the pool are up and responding.  Monitoring server availability is not intrinsically implied with consistent hashing.

You can check each server before you attempt to connect, and modify your connection pool based on your checks. You can store the available server list for the pool elsewhere and have some other process constantly watching and modifying the available server list. You could just assume they are always all up, and only check which ones need to be removed on a failure, or you can use any combination of the above.  The bottom line is that predis does not, at the moment, do it for you.